# Non-maxima suppression in OpenCV / EmguCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, emgucv

Non-maxima suppression seems to be a built in component of some openCV functions used for corner detection (like cornerHarris, goodFeaturesToTrack etc.). But, I would like to apply non-maxima suppression directly (on its own) to an image. Is there to achieve this in OpenCV (Emgu CV is what I'm using)?